# Backing Bean Initialization

Tags: jsf

I have a variable in backing bean that needs to get reset to null whenever the associated page is opened using the relevant menu link. Is there a way to run a initialization code in the backing bean whenever the relevant menu link is clicked? Contsructor runs only the first time the menu link is clicked. I guess the bean is then retained in the jsf context and is not getting recreated. Is there a way to ensure a new object of that backing bean is created each time the menu link is clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just put the bean in request scope?

Another option would be to use a setpropertyactionlistener on the menu.  When the menu is clicked, set the value to "null".

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

1 . Change the bean to the request-scoped bean

2 . Use the `action` attribute to call the method on the backing bean to run the initialization code whenever the link is clicked , something like this:

```
 <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.init}" value="My Link" />
```

And `myBean.init()` contains the initialization code

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I tried changing it into "request" scope but some of the validation messages are not getting displayed (need to see why). Apart from that when I used action="#{managedbean.init}" , it is throwing up "viewexpired" exception and showing up a different link in address bar if I click on the relevant menu item first time the page loads. When i click on some other menu item and click this link then it opens up properly.